# Create a test Environment for existing PHP/MySQL website

Tags: php, mysql

I am new to PHP/MySQL.
We have a Production PHP Website (MySQL, Apache, Windows 2008) and have been given a test server(Windows 2008,PHP, MySQL, Apache already installed) to setup a test environment for this website.

We would like to upload the production website on this test server.

Could someone let me know the complete set of instructions on how we could achieve that?

Thanks
Aslam

Comment: Do you have cpanel on production server?

Comment: if you're using virtualbox, you can just duplicate the image of the production and place it to your test server

Comment: Both are windows and I don't find cpanel installed on production.              Below are the steps I can think of:

Download all the files via FTP and then upload them to the test environment.
Take a backup / export the database and the restore / import the MySQL database to the test environment.

However, I don't know how to create a test URL for my website on the test server?

Comment: Hello folks, Could someone please help me here?